# Array, Check if value exists

Tags: php, arrays

Let's just say I have this:

```
$A = "1,2,3,4";
$B = "2";
```

How do you check if `$B` exists in `$A`?

**EDIT**:
The $A is actually an array in my code:

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4);
$B = "2";
```

Comment: If `$A` is "actually" an array, then post it as such. Don't give us this broken pseudo code that doesn't actually represent your real problem and expect us to product a useful solution. If `$A` is actually an array, then you want `in_array`, which would have been really easy to find with even the laziest googling.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php ?

Comment: I can make it just as stated in my post, no need to post the array.

Comment: @StefanTeunissen No, you can't. You're required to produce a minimal complete example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: My 'problem' is that I want to know if $B exists in $A no matter if it's an array or not.

Comment: _no matter if it's an array or not_. you need different functionality if it is not an array..

Comment: Yes, that's why I was actually asking for help as not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = 2;
```

Then what you want is [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if( in_array($b, $a) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the only one that is most likely human on this website ;) I will accept answer asap

Comment: @StefanTeunissen No need to insult everyone. They're just trying to help you get better answers, and improve the overall quality of the site.

Comment: How can it improve the quality of the site with a community like this? A fried posted a question, but was stated as "not a real question". And let me tell you, anything with a question mark is a question. Right?

Comment: @StefanTeunissen People do sometimes get a bit overzealous, so I'm sorry for that. But you might want to read over the "How do I ask a good question?" page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid these situations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array_flip(array(1,2,3,4));
$b = 2;

if (isset($a[$b])) {
    echo 'bingo';
}
```